# Submit without refresh in django

Tags: python, ajax, django, submit

i have a html form and submit button (It adds or removes relations in manytomanyfield "users"):

```
{% if user in event.users.all %}
     <form action="/event/{{ event.id }}/" method="GET">
            <input type="hidden" value="{{ event.id }}" name="remove">
            <input type="submit" value="Remove">
      </form>
{% else %}
     <form action="/event/{{ event.id }}/" method="GET">
            <input type="hidden" value="{{ event.id }}" name="add">
            <input type="submit" value="Add">
      </form>
```

in views.py:

```
def show_event(request, event_id):
    ...
    event = get_object_or_404(Event, id=event_id)
    user = request.user
    if request.GET.get('add'):
        event.users.add(user)
        event.save()
    if request.GET.get('remove'):
        event.users.remove(user)
        event.save()
    return render(request, 'events/event.html', {'event':event, 'user':user,})
```

This function works fine, but the page refreshes after submitting form. I need no refresh and i need to change button text just like "Follow" button in Twitter. I tried to use some jquery\ajax but i dont exactly understand how it should work. Can please anyone explain how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the ajax/javascript you've tried that doesn't work? What errors was it producing?

Comment: @CurtisOlson i think things i tried have absolutely no sense, so i just cant understand what to do to make this submit button something like twitter's follow button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an extremely basic ajax example. In your form, you can fire your ajax method with:

```
<a onclick="AjaxFormSubmit()" href="#">Submit</a>
```

Then your ajax method would be as follows:

```
function AjaxFormSubmit() {
    $.ajax({
        url : '/event/{{ event.id }}/',
        type : "POST",
        data : { the_post : $('#id-of-your-field').val() }
    }).done(function(returned_data){

        // This is the ajax.done() method, where you can fire events after the ajax method is complete 

        // For instance, you could hide/display your add/remove button here

    });
}
```

I recommend looking at the [Ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to see all of the Ajax methods available to you.

Also, in your view, you'll need to return (in this example) json data via an HttpResponse. i.e.

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(your_data))
# I like to return success/fail Booleans, personally
```

*Note, this is untested code.

Comment: where should i place this ajax method?

Comment: Somewhere below your form or in an external .js file. If you use an external .js file, you obviously won't be able to use django's template syntax for the `event.id`, but you can just pass that as an argument to `AjaxFormSubmit`

Comment: where are in this code remove and add values in GET query?

Comment: Well I'm going to suggest you use a POST method since you're adding/removing records, and you'll also need to pass form data through the method with a data argument. I'll update my answer. I also recommend experimenting with Ajax first to get an idea of how it works. Try making a get request with it and returning nothing but a boolean from a view. Then you'll know your heading in the right direction.